# Find taylor series for $x/1+x$, at $x= -2$ using differentiation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

Attempt:

$\\f^ 1(x) = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$ ,
$\\f^ 2(x) = \frac{-2}{(1+x)^3}$ ,
$\\f^ 3 (x) = \frac{6}{(1+x)^4}$

$\\f^ n (x) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n!)}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$,
$\\f^ n (-2) = \frac{(-1)^{n+1}(n!)}{(-1)^{n+1}}$

Using the taylor series formula,

$\frac {x}{1+x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{f^n(-2)}{n!} (x+2)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n!}{n!}(x+2)^n
= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x+2)^n $

But the solution used geometric series and $\frac {x}{1+x} = 1 + \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (x+2)^n$.

I am unsure as to what is wrong with my solution, is there a  way to get this  correct answer using taylor series formula directly instead of using geometric series?

Comment: $f(-2)=2$, so the first term is different.

Comment: The differentiated terms are wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Make life simpler letting $x=y-2$. So
$$\frac x{1+x}=\frac{y-2}{y-1}=1+\frac{1}{1-y}$$

The derivatives wrt $y$ are very simple and, when finished, make $y= {x+2}$

Comment: @Martund. Thanks for pointing my stupidity ! In fact, I missed the minus. Cheers :-(

Comment: I understand how to use the geometric series to do the question, but if I were to use the Taylor series formula directly, I do not get the same answer

Comment: @user594831. This is for making the Taylor series in a simpler way.

Comment: Thank you, this gave the correct answer. If I differentiate directly without replacing x with y - 2, it's harder but I should still get the same answer right? My attempt above is missing the '+1' when I differentiate with x directly.